# ASP.NET MVC3 database deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created application in mvc3 and I used the default account controller for my users.
I followed instructions from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs to put all tables (from aspnetdb) in one database.

My trouble is how to set webconfig and connection string corectly?
I set the conn string to my databse but if I try to register Visual studio create aspnetdb and put my user info there.
I am trying to find solution to stop vs creating aspnetdb.
My hosting provider is http://www.inside.hr it is hosting company from Croatia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shared hosting environment only allows you to use one database, you can add the ASP.NET Membership database tables to your existing database. Joe Stagner has a walkthrough on how to do that [here](http://www.msjoe.com/2010/07/adding-asp-net-membership-to-your-own-database/).

Can you update your question to tell us where you're hosting? That will help.

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than one database? You shouldn't need to use a repository just to use two databases, although that's a good pattern to move to for other reasons.

Comment: Yes i can have more then one database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow you correctly, but did you try something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MyDevArmyDB" connectionString="Data Source=DATASOURCE;Initial Catalog=devarmydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Password=PASSWORDSTRING"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

DATASOURCE- replace with the address of your database
USERID- replace with the actual user id
PASSWORDSTRING- replace with the actual password

Accessing the DB is done like this:

```
public class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private DataContext dataContext;
    private Table<User> usersTable;

    public IQueryable<User> Users { get { return usersTable; } }

    public SqlUsersRepository(string databaseName)
    {
        HttpRequestWrapper request = new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(request.ApplicationPath);
        dataContext = new DataContext(config.GetConnetionString(databaseName));
    }
}
```

Note that GetConnectionString is an extension function which supports encryption/decryption of the connection string (if you decide to protect the connection string):

```
public static class ConfigExtension
{
    public static string GetConnetionString(this Configuration config, string databaseName, string provider = "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider")
    {
        string sectionName = "connectionStrings";
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
            config.Save();
        }

        return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[databaseName].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: connection string like that i tryed, but this class SqlUserRepository i should add in my models or what?

Comment: @Goran, it could be part of your user model (and I define in the same place I define the user model) but as far as I've seen it should be only used by your Controller.

Comment: did you try this on server actually? as default my accountmodel.cs is in models folder, class ConfigExtension is for?

Comment: @Goran, yes I tried it on my web site. I just made my web site: www.mydevarmy.com and I tested it there (i.e. if you click on my Users button you will see a list of users, which are fetched from a database). In the beginning it seems a little complex to do, but the idea is actually very clever: having a user repository allows you to use Inversion of Control when creating your Controller (i.e. your controller doesn't need to know which repository it uses) and it also makes testing much easier.

Comment: @Goran the `ConfigExtension` allows you to call `config.GetConnectionString(...)` on your `Configuration` object. `Configuration` does not contain a `GetConnectionString` function, but you add it by writing a static extension class.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary just to point the ASP.NET Membership at a different database. That's just a matter of changing the connection string in web.config, right?

Comment: @Jon, that's all I had to do... I just changed the connection string and I was immediately able to connect to my database (located on the web host).